# Can not add2cart grouped product when 1 input field is diabled

Tags: magento2, php, module, addtocart, grouped-products

I need to disable the input field when customergroup = 0 or 1 and quantity is < 0 but when I add the argument 'disabled' to the input, the  add2cart button does not put the other available items in the cart anymore.

```
   <input type="number"
                                       name="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
                                       data-selector="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
                                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getQty() * 1) ?>"
                                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                                       class="input-text qty"
                                       min="0"
                                       data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                                       data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"
                                    <?php if ($disable_box === '1'  && ($block->getStockStatus($_item) == '1' || $block->getStockStatus($_item) == '0' )) {echo 'disabled';} ?> />
                            </div>
```

[image: disabled inputboxes]

Answer (score 0):

The element with attribute `disabled` will not pass the value to form.

You can use `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled` or render additional element like `<input type=hidded.../>` for pass `0` value.

Answer (score 0):

I have notice that, I have resolved it now like this:

```
  {echo 'readonly style="background-color:#D3D3D3;border-color:#D3D3D3;"';} ?>
```